# Get Request with PNG as return type

Tags: swift, get, png, endpoint

I am making a get request to an endpoint with the end goal of getting an image back and then displaying it. However, the endpoint I need to use returns the type of .png. Is it possible to parse this? If so, how can we parse this in swift?

Here is an example get endpoint to call the get request on: `https://sleepercdn.com/avatars/db0ab21340b151507e6b7152ba6539db`

Comment: `.png` is an image type.  UIKit has support for PNG

Comment: You just need to rename the downloaded file and add the PNG pathExtension

Answer (score 1):

try this approach, to "parse" an image from your response and displaying it in a View.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var img = UIImage()
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: img)
            .onAppear {
                getImage()
            }
    }

    func getImage() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://sleepercdn.com/avatars/db0ab21340b151507e6b7152ba6539db") else { return }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            if let data = data,
               let image = UIImage(data: data) { // <-- here
                 self.img = image // <-- here
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: did my answer not worked for you? Works well for me, tested on ios-16 devices and  macos 13.

Comment: Well, I like your answer even if nobody else can be bothered to upvote it.